# Is using LIKE '%%x%%' different than using LIKE '%x%'?

Tags: sql

I am looking at a stored procedure written by another programmer and I see they are using

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.names WHERE name LIKE '%%st%%ack%%flow%%'
```

and I have never seen this notation before. My assumption is that this would behave the same way as

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.names WHERE name LIKE '%st%ack%flow%'
```

but I have never seen this before and I see nothing online that discusses using double percents in a LIKE statement like this before. Can someone explain the possible difference between the two?

I expect that using %% and % in a LIKE statement are interchangeable and they should never produce different results.

Comment: He might be confusing with embedded SQL where percent signs need to be escaped in some cases. But functionally should be no differences, other than maybe a bit slower because the expression is a little more complex.

Comment: Are you seeing the `%%` in a string formatting context? As in, with `printf` function in C, or `String.format` in Java, or something similar?

Comment: @mypetition No this is in a T-SQL query context.

Comment: @MatthewI yes, I understand that. What I mean is, did you see the first example in a, let's say, a `String` in a Java application, and that Java application was passing the string to the database driver library. For example: `connectionObject.executeQuery( String.format( "Example 1 with the %%s", parameters, for, the, string, formatting) );` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is literaly no difference between:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.names WHERE name LIKE '%%st%%ack%%flow%%'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.names WHERE name LIKE '%st%ack%flow%'
```

`%` wildcard allows any or no characters.

---

The only difference is when `%` is escaped:

```
CREATE TABLE names(name VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO names(name) VALUES('%b');
INSERT INTO names(name) VALUES('%ab');

SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '%%b';
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '%%b' ESCAPE '%';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b611dd6c7259016d1043cbd7ac7e8d3d)**